# PHP - Notice: Undefined Index

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, multilingual, undefined-index

I know how to do the isset thing, and I also know that the notice itself is no biggie, but it still bothers my ocd.

This is how my page handling the variables in the mentioned lines is set up:

```
//this part gets the page name from the url or sets the name to "Home"
if (isset($_GET['page'])):
    $pageCurrent = ucfirst($_GET['page']);
else:
    $pageCurrent = 'Home';
endif;

//this is a multiple array to handle the error pages
$errorPages = array(
    '404' => array(
        'errorTitle' => 'title',
        'error' => 'content'    
    ),
    '403' => array(
        'errorTitle' => 'title',
        'error' => 'content'        
    )
);

//this two lines are the bastards giving me a hard time
$errorTitle = $errorPages[$pageCurrent]['errorTitle'];
$error = $errorPages[$pageCurrent]['error'];
```

You can view the whole thing on [GitHub](https://github.com/andyosuna/andyosuna.com/blob/master/cd/en.php)

Thanks

Comment: Is that a valid php code for if else?

Comment: @kimbarcelona Yes. http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php

Comment: Got it. Well, I'm not used to use that syntax for if else.

Comment: Is it just me or... if your pageCurrent is set to 'Home', and you do errorPages['Home'] , that doesn't exist in your errorPages array... so...

Comment: of course its supposed to show that, what if `$pageCurrent == 'Home'`, then its undefined, just add another checking isset on `$errorPages[$pageCurrent]`

Comment: @olive_tree The exact point/question I was about to make/ask.

Comment: @olive_tree the error shows on anything but the error pages, so you are correct, but doing the isset on the $errorPages didn't fix it, I had tried it already...

Comment: @andyosuna what olive_tree is saying, that you're trying to reference `$errorPages['Home']['errorTitle']` and you haven't set this index in your array. You're essentially trying to make reference to something that doesn't exist in your array

Comment: I had to step away and have a smoke for a minute, I had been staring at this for too long. I did an if statement checking for $pageCurrent to be equal to the values of the error pages, a little too bulky for my liking but that fixed it. Thank you guys! Ghost  olive_tree and Bankzilla

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, the error message is occurring because you are referencing a key/value that doesn't exist in your `$errorPages` array.

When accessing values in an array, you must be sure that the key you are using exists. In your case you can use `isset` for this:

```
if(isset($errorPages[$pageCurrent])) {

}
```

Alternatively you can use `array_key_exists` ([documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php))

`isset` will return false if the key exists but is set to `null`. `array_key_exists` will only return false if the key has never been set, or has been `unset` in the array.